# Disabling executing a subroutine in perl in the DEBUG mode

Tags: perl, debugging, subroutine

Is it possible to disable execution of a specific subroutine, when we are executing the script in DEBUG mode?.

Supoose, sub tryme is being called and takes quite a long time to execute, I would like to disable/skip executing the subroutine.

- One option available is to comment the call - editing the script is not recommended
- Modify a variable which is checked in tryme() - the sub routine does not have that facility
- Hence, can we use any of the DEBUG options to disabling executing the subroutine

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can set a global Variable or a Command-Line Variable to set (for example) `$debug = 1`. Then you could specifiy your sub-calls like that:

```
_long_function() unless $debug == 1;
```

or

```
unless ($debug) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$^P` variable contains flags determining which debug mode is currently active. Therefore, we can write code that shows completely different behaviour in the debugger:

```
$ cat heisenbug.pl
use List::Util qw/sum/;
if ($^P) {
  print "You are in the debugger. Flags are ", unpack("b*", $^P), "\n";
} else {
  print "sum = ", sum(@ARGV), "\n";
}
$ perl heisenbug.pl 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
sum = 55
$ perl -d heisenbug.pl 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-:2):        if ($^P) {
  DB<1> n
main::(-:3):          print "You are in the debugger. Flags are ", unpack("b*", $^P), "\n";
  DB<1> n
You are in the debugger. Flags are 10001100000111001010110010101100
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.  
  DB<1> q
$
```

The variable and the meaning of the flags are documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24PERLDB)

Answer (score 0):

You can check environment variable like this:

```
_long_function()   if $ENV{ DEBUG };
```

And run script like next if you want to this `_long_function` to execute:

```
DEBUG=1 ./script.pl
```

In normal cases the `_long_function` will not be called:

```
./script.pl
```